# Nothing is being displayed after form is submitted (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to secure my web page for a while now by preventing sql injection. However, now nothing is being displayed on the page at all after I submit my form. Here is my complete code because I don't know where my error is occurring.

```
   <?php
   require_once 'db_connect.php';
   ?>
   <head> 
   <title> Data </title>
   <link href = "ss2.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" >
   </head>
  <body>
  <h1> Research Center </h1>
  <a href = "home.php"> Data Home Page </a>

  <ol class = 'instructions'>

  <li> Step 1: Please select your first year you want to gather data from. </li>
  <li> Step 2: Next, select a second year to create a time interval. </li>
  <li> Step 3: Then, select the time of year you want to retrieve data from. </li>
  <li> Step 4: Finally, specify a specific regional location. </li>

  </ol>


  <form action="unemployed2.php" method ="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

  <fieldset>
  <legend>
  Specify Date, Month, and County
  </legend>
  <p class = 'year'>
  <label for="year">
  Please Select years: From 
  </label>

  <select name= 'year'>
  <option value= ''> </option>
  <?php
  $query = "select distinct year from unemployed";

  $result = $conn->query($query);
  while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
   }
  ?>
  </select>
  </p>

  <p class = 'year'>
  <label for="year">
  To
  </label>

  <select name= 'year2'>
  <option value= ''> </option>
  <?php
  $query = "select distinct year from unemployed";

  $result = $conn->query($query);
  while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
   }
  ?>
  </select>
  </p>


  <p>
  <label for="month">
  Please select a month
  <label>

  <select name= 'month'>
  <option value= ''> </option>
  <?php
  $query = "select distinct month from unemployed";

  $result = $conn->query($query);
  while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<option value='".$row->month."'>".$row->month."</option>";
   }
  ?>
  <option value = "All Months"> All Months </option>
  </select>
  </p>

  <p>
  <label for="location">
  Please specify a location
  </label>

  <select name='location'>
  <option value= ''> </option>

  <option value = 'Fayette'> Fayette County (IN) </option>
  <option value = 'Henry'> Henry County (IN) </option>
  <option value = 'Randolph'> Randolph County (IN) </option>
  <option value = 'Rush'> Rush County (IN) </option>
  <option value = 'Union'> Union County (IN) </option>
 <option value = 'Wayne'> Wayne County (IN) </option>
 <option value = 'INCounties'> Local Indiana Counties </option>
 <option value = 'Indiana'> Indiana </option>
 <option value = 'Butler'> Butler County (OH) </option>
 <option value = 'Darke'> Darke County (OH) </option>
 <option value = 'Mercer'> Mercer County (OH) </option>
 <option value = 'Preble'> Preble County (OH) </option>
 <option value = 'OHCounties'> Local Ohio Counties </option>
 <option value = 'Ohio'> Ohio </option>
 <option value = 'US'> United States </option>

 </select>
 </p>


 <input type ="submit" />

 </fieldset>
 </form>

<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {


  $gYear = $_POST["year"];
  $gYear2 = $_POST["year2"];
 $gMonth = $_POST["month"];


 $array = array('loc1' => 'Fayette', 'loc2' => 'Henry', 'loc3' => 'Randolph', 
         'loc4' => 'Rush', 'loc5' => 'Union', 'loc6' => 'Wayne',
         'loc7' => 'INCounties','loc8' => 'Indiana', 'loc9' => 'Butler', 'loc10' => 'Darke',
         'loc11' => 'Mercer', 'loc12' => 'Preble', 'loc13' => 'OHCounties',
         'loc14' => 'Ohio', 'loc15' => 'US');

 if ($gYear > $gYear2) {

 die('ERROR: Your second year cant be a time period before the first year you selected');
 }

 else {

 if (array_key_exists($_POST["location"], $array)) {

 $column = $_POST["location"];
 }

 else {
 echo "ERROR";
 }



 $sql = "SELECT `$column`, `Year`, `Month` FROM unemployed WHERE year BETWEEN ? AND ? and month= ?";
 $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $query->bind_param('sss', $gyear, $gYear2, $gMonth);

 $query->execute(); 
 $result = $query->get_result();

 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Month</th><th>$column</th></tr>";

 while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo $row->$column;
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row->Year;
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row->Month;
 echo "</td></tr>";

 }

 $query->close();



 echo "</table>";

 }
 } // end of main if statement

 ?>

 </body>
```

If I had to guess, my error lies within these lines of code because the web page shows ERROR after I push the submit button:

```
$array = array('loc1' => 'Fayette', 'loc2' => 'Henry', 'loc3' => 'Randolph', 
             'loc4' => 'Rush', 'loc5' => 'Union', 'loc6' => 'Wayne',
             'loc7' => 'INCounties','loc8' => 'Indiana', 'loc9' => 'Butler', 'loc10' => 'Darke',
             'loc11' => 'Mercer', 'loc12' => 'Preble', 'loc13' => 'OHCounties',
             'loc14' => 'Ohio', 'loc15' => 'US');
else {

     if (array_key_exists($_POST["location"], $array)) {

     $column = $_POST["location"];
     }

     else {
     echo "ERROR";
     }
```

Does anyone know what my error is? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lot of code mate... Less is more!

Comment: I know, but I really don't know where in my code that my error is occurring. I'm sorry for the big mess of code!

Comment: Then use breakpoints. Try to print something in different places to see where it is breaking. You will be able to print before it breaks. Or enable warnings and errors. Just debug :)

Comment: So start using debug statements, e.g. `echo 'about to ...'` and `echo 'done with ....'` type stuff, so you can trace the program flow.

Comment: Switch on PHP's error reporting flags so you can see the errors. Or failing that, check in the server log.

Answer (score 0):

add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors",1); at the top of your code, and check for an error

Comment: If the problem is a syntax error error, this won't help, as the program will fail to parse. Better to set these flags in either the `php.ini` or `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I think is not working is this line of code in your second code block:

```
if (array_key_exists($_POST["location"], $array)) {
```

This will never return true, because the values in your select input in your HTML code are not the keys of $array, but the values. So $_POST["location"] will always contain a value in $array, not a key. So `array_key_exists` will always return false in that line of code.

That means the else-block will be executed, which will cause "ERROR" to be printed.

Did you mean to use `in_array($_POST["location"], $array)` ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)) instead, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

From your code `ERROR` is printed in the else check of: `array_key_exists($_POST["location"], $array)`. Check your database make sure there are no nulls and the values are exactly what is placed in your mapping array `$array`, keys are case-sensitive.

Also, you don't need an `else` after a `die()` statement, as the program has stopped. You can leave your structure like:

```
if (...) die();

//rest of code
```

Also try to format properly, or at least stick to a readable structure, e.g.:

```
function () {
    if () {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking your array of locations for a matching key, but your location is actually a value. You are also repeating your locations twice. I would recommend creating a $locations array at the top of your file, use it to populate your option tags and then also use it for your validation test. This will result in your "array_key_exists" test doing what you expect it to.

```
<?php

// top

$locations = array(
    'Fayette'       => 'Fayette Counter (IN)',
    'Henry'         => 'Henry County (IN)',
    'Randolph'      => 'Randolph County (IN)',
    'Rush'          => 'Rush County (IN)',
    'Union'         => 'Union County (IN)',
    'Wayne'         => 'Wayne County (IN)',
    'INCounties'    => 'Local Indiana Counties (IN)',
    'Indiana'       => 'Indiana',
    'Butler'        => 'Butler County (OH)',
    'Darke'         => 'Darke County (OH)',
    'Mercer'        => 'Mercer County (OH)',
    'Preble'        => 'Preble County (OH)',
    'OHCounties'    => 'Local Ohio Counties',
    'Ohio'          => 'Ohio',
    'US'            => 'United States'
);

?>

<!-- middle -->

<select name='location'>
    <option value= ""> </option>
    <?php

    foreach($locations as $k => $v){
        echo "<option value=\"{$k}\">{$v}</option>";
    }

    ?>
</select>

<?php

// bottom

if (array_key_exists($_POST["location"], $locations)){
    $column = $_POST["location"];
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```